# Update jython.jar in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, jython, pydev

What is the proper way to apply a new jython.jar to PyDev?

I expect this option to be available since I have to supply a Jython interpreter at startup. Using mixed versions would likely cause issues. I expected the jython.jar for that interpreter to be used for everything, not just running standalone Jython, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I believe org.python.pydev.jython provides a version of jython.jar. The version of this plugin in PyDev 2.7.1 has a pydev-jython.jar that is on the runtime classpath when I import this plugin. (The import also makes a copy of the directory of my configured Jython interpreter.)

How do I get PyDev to use a different jython.jar?

Here is some more background information.

I have followed the instructions on the PyDev website for installing PyDev in Eclipse. I have configured Jython 2.5.3 to be the interpreter.

I can open a Jython console and run the following:

```
>>> import org.python.core.PySystemState as pss
>>> st = pss()
>>> st.getBuiltins
<bound method <reflected field public org.python.core.PyObject org.python.core.PySystemState.__name__ at 0x1>.getBuiltins of <module 'sys' (built-in)>>
```

I also have no problem doing this from a python module that I run as a Jython Run.

However, when I try to access getBuiltins from java, I get a compile-time error stating that the method getBuiltins is not defined for PySystemState. As I have fought with this problem extensively, I believe what is going on is that org.python.pydev.jython is providing jython.jar whereas the interpreter configuration is only used to run the Jython interpreter.

Clearly, some jython.jar is in my classpath because I don't get a complaint when I import org.python.core.PySystemState. The symptoms are consistent with an older jython.jar that didn't have the full API of Jython 2.5.3.

Any help would be appreciated -- I'd prefer not to earn another tumbleweed bronze! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I was trying to do required access to a new jython.jar. It had nothing to do with PyDev. I just created a plugin from jython.jar and referenced it.

I thought there were issues with PyDev because classpath and jythonpath worked automatically from the java app but not from a plugin product configuration. It turns out Eclipse was handling it for me in one case and not the other. PyDev simply wasn't invovled.